# How to configure Kubenetes to make external requests going from a static IP

Tags: kubernetes, routes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, static-ip-address

I have a bunch of pods and corresponding cluster IP services running in a Kubenetes cluster. I use an Ingress controller to route incoming traffic to these workloads.

Now, when I make an external request from within a workload, I would like those requests to go out from a static IP.

1. Are both incoming and outgoing traffic handled via the same network interface?
2. How do I set a static IP for my outgoing requests from a pod

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on AWS or GKE the only way to get a static outbound from an (autoscaling) node pool is via a NAT gateway. On GKE you are also required to have private nodes (no public ips).

Kubernetes ingress, at least in GKE, is treated separately from egress and is a different load balancer.

https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example

Answer (score 0):

Some research showed me the following method and it worked:

1. Create a new node pool with a specific label (lets say `ip=static`)
2. Deploy the workload with the following selector

   ```
    nodeSelector:
      ip: static
   ```
3. Through VPC Network, reserve an external static IP
4. Assign this IP to the VM which is used by the new node pool

However, as the @user578582 has mentioned, when the scaling is done, I will have to use a NAT gateway to make all the outbound traffic to go from a static IP under this configuration.